# Code issue with AngularJS and JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a JSON source and want to get results from it with a post request.

When I test with POSTMAN extension in chorme it works really well. But when I do that with angularJS the page keep loading and chrome consoles shows errors.

My code is here:

```
angular.module('loginApp', []).controller('loginController', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.userName = '';
$scope.userPass = '';
$scope.output = function () {
    var params = JSON.stringify({
            username: '******',
            password: '******'
        });
    $http({url: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/user/login.json",
        method: 'POST',
        data: params,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response;
    });
};
});
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: what is the error in console??

Comment: Try without stringifying and specifying headers, this type of a request should work out of the box.

Comment: I have tried it without stringify()... and headers are specified

Comment: @LaxmikantDange errors in the consoles are: Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
angular.js:11607 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at Error (native)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:6:417
    at l.$digest

Comment: (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:123:469)
    at l.$apply(http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:126:58)
    at l (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:81:171)
    at S (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:85:301)
    at XMLHttpRequest.D.onload (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:86:315)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11607
angular.js:14500 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$rootScope/infdig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, and after post error if occured:

```
var LoginApp = angular.module('loginApp', []);
LoginApp.controller('loginController', function ($scope, $common) {
    $scope.userName = '';
    $scope.userPass = '';

    $scope.output = function () {
        var params = JSON.stringify({
            username: '******',
            password: '******'
        });

        $common.ajax("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/user/login.json", params, "POST").then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        });
    };
});

LoginApp.factory("$common", function($http, $q) {
    function ajax(url, param, method) {
        var request = $http({
            method: method,
            url: url,
            data:param
        });

        var promise = request.then(
            function(response) {
                return(response.data);
            },
            function(response) {
                console.log("Ocurred error: " + response);
                return($q.reject("Something went wrong"));
            }
        );
        return promise;
    }
    return({
        ajax:ajax
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm talking about this: headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }

Comment: Ok have tried it and it shows Error Occurred [OBJECT] [OBJECT] ... But it seems like a infinite loop

Comment: OK, change this  console.log("Ocurred error: " + response); for this:  console.log(response). After post error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91302/discussion-between-omer-and-emir-marques).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.output = function () {
    var params = {
      username: '******',
      password: '******'
    };

    $http.post("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/user/login.json", params)
      .then(function (response) {
        return response;
      });
};
```

Also you should move your `http` request to a `service`. It's a bad practice put it in a `controller`.

Comment: Its shows this error in console if do it that way: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized : CSRF validation failed)